# Adding to remote DB

Tags: mysql, objective-c

I'm trying to add data to a remote MySQL database and it works perfect until I add a SPACE to my text fill in order to write the second word. Can someone help me out with this? Here's the code

```
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender {
    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://pruebapestana.comoj.com/juancho4.php?name=%@&last=%@&age=%@",_name.text, _last.text, _age.text];
```

Comment: You don't add data to a remote DB from Xcode. You can do so from your iOS app or OS X program, but not Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Spaces are not valid characters in a URL. You need to properly escape them so they become `%20`. The best way to do this is to use the `NSString` method `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`.

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://pruebapestana.comoj.com/juancho4.php?name=%@&last=%@&age=%@",
    [_name.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], 
    [_last.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], 
    [_age.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

This will properly escape any other special values in addition to the spaces.